For the linear operator $T$ on the vector space $V$, find an ordered basis for the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by the vector $z$.
For the linear operator $T$ on the vector space $V$, find an ordered basis for the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by the vector $z$.
$$V=M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R), T(A)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 2&& 2\end{pmatrix}A, z=\begin{pmatrix} 0 && 1\\ 1&& 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
The T-cyclic subspace $W$ of $V$ generated by $z$ is $W=\text{span}\{ z,T(z), T^2(z),\cdots\}.$
Now, $T(z)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 2&& 2\end{pmatrix}, T^2(z)=3\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 2&& 2\end{pmatrix}, T^3(x)=3^2\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 2&& 2\end{pmatrix}$ and so on.
So, we can say that $T^k(z)=3^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 2&& 2\end{pmatrix}.$
But, I can't seem to find a basis for $W$. I know the standard theorem which states that:

Let T be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $\mathrm{V},$ and let $\mathrm{W}$ denote the $\mathrm{T}$-cyclic subspace of $\mathrm{V}$ generated by a nonzero vector $v \in \mathrm{V} .$ Let $k=\operatorname{dim}(\mathrm{W}) .$
Then $\left\{v, \mathrm{T}(v), \mathrm{T}^{2}(v), \ldots, \mathrm{T}^{k-1}(v)\right\}$ is a basis for $\mathrm{W}$.

However, I don't know what $\dim (W)$ is. Is there a way on how to find what $\dim (W)=k$ is? I can't seem to solve this problem without knowing the value is $k.$

$\dim(W)$ should be $\leq 4$, and since $z\neq0$, it should be at least $1$. So, start searching for $2,3,4$. Is $T(z)$ linearly independent from $z$? Is it isn't, the dimension is $1$. If it is, check if $T^2(z)$ is independent of $z,T(z)$. If it is, then the dimension is $2$. If not, check if $T^{3}(z)$ is independent of $z,T(z), T^2(z)$. If it isn't, the dimension is $3$. If it is, the dimension is $4$.

@ameg Wait, $z,T(z)$ are linearly independent and that means $\dim(W)\geq 2$ but then again, $z,T(z),T^2(z)$ does not form a linearly independent set. But that does not mean the dimension of $W$ is 2 as although $z,T(z),T^2(z)$ is not a linearly independent set but one doesn't know whether or not $\exists k\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $z,T(z),T^k(z)$ is linearly independent. So, what to do now?

$T$ is linear. As soon as $T^2(z)=az+bT(z)$, then all other powers of $T$ are dependent too. $T^3(z)=aT(z)+bT^2(z)=aT(z)+baz+b^2T(z)$. ... To see it in general, use division with remainder $x^n=(a+bx-x^2)q(z)+r(x)$, for some polynomials $q$ and $r$, with $\deg(r)<2$. Therefore, $T^n(z)=(a+bT-T^2)(z)q(T)(z)+r(T)(z)=r(T)(z)$. The last equation is because $az+bT(z)-T^2(z)=0$. Since $\deg(r)$ is at most $1$, this equation expresses $T^n(z)$ in terms of $z$ and $T(z)$.
